# Forecasting that FFT result

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, fourier-series

I have the following FFT result charts. Searching for a way to forecast the future AMPLITUDE steps from the Time Domain Plot if possible, or the next maximum/minimum deviation based on some previous AMPLITUDE in time.

Is that possible when we have a Frequency Domain Plot which looks like that:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can certainly do an inverse transform, but it will probably (certainly)  be wrong.  You might get a reasonable estimate using ARMA methods, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model, but the frequency spectrum doesn't look right to me.  So if we punt and assume it's "noise" then you can use various noise techniques.  The first thing is to plot and analyze the first differences since you want step size.  That may or may not help but will allow you to work with what you want.   In any case, provide a link to the real data and other instances.

Comment: @rrogers This is linked to the research of W.D.Gann. and it is the holy grail of forex markets. If you are able to help me I will share the other part.

Comment: To be constructive (I probably should delete the last comment); you look for a good model.  That means the residuals conform to one of the standard distributions; normally, lognormal, etc ...  I usually use the normal,...  probability plots.  Then you examine  the profile of the distributions to look for 1/f characteristics, jumps, and nonlinearities,  There are other tests that are occasionally possible.  Then subtract (and scale if you must) the residuals (as much as is reasonable)  and examine your model for "reasonableness".   ARMA is a reasonable start.

Comment: If that doesn't work; then do the same for the first differences.  If that succeeds you are probably into 1/f territory.  I never quite got why that fallback works better than the original.  More extensively you can apply the techniques in "The Algebra of Random Variables" by Marvin Springer.  If you go down that route, there should be part of Mathematica that can implement it; H-transforms.  A friend used that book to implement hunting for "black swans" and I am sure he put the work there.  But ... it might have been for an insurance company.

Comment: There is one more item.  Looking at your graphs, there is a way to purify the frequency plots, maybe, that will yield a virtually noise-free inverse.  This involves a test of the frequency humps but might work.  In any case, read the book "The Quants" by Scott Peterson :); many smart people got burnt in the 200xs by trusting modeling/tricks too much.  As did "Long Term Investment" in the 199xs.